# Ответ от сервера в течении определенного времени

Tags: axios, nestjs, rxjs

Суть в чём: использую Nest.js. Мой GET запрос в сервисе отправляет POST запрос на создание заказа, но момент в том, что сервер, к которому идёт запрос обрабатывает его(запрос) порядка 8 секунд, и соответственно я получаю сразу неполный ответ, но со статусом 201. Могу ли я посредством rxjs + axios сделать запрос такого формата: запрос --> подожди 8 секунд --> отдай ответ.

Или проще это сделать каким-нибудь setTimeout?

Comment: Что значит - не полный ответ?

Comment: @SwaD пример: создаю заказ, а на сервере они обрабатываются не сразу, а в течении 8-ми секунд и только после этого я получаю правильное тело запроса. Тот ответ, что я сразу получаю - это тело запроса, но многие данные имеют значение null

Comment: Ну так сервер не должен отправлять "пустые данные". Запрос пришел, обработался и только после этого ответ.